# Exclude some properties when searching an object in a list

Tags: java, arraylist

I use this code to check if an object is already in a list

```
myClientList.contains(client);
```

I want to exclude some properties when checking in the client exist in the list, such as `adress`, `age` ... and just check the `firstName`, `lastName` and age. Is there any option to make that when using `myClientList.contains` or shall I write my own function to do it ?

Comment: `myClientList.contains(client);` relies on the implementation of `equals` method. you should implement that accordingly if this matches the _general equality_ of your _client_ objects. (don't forget `hashcode` then) otherwise, if you need only a somehow_temporary_ definition of equality you should rather use some kind of filtering.

Comment: `contains` works off `equals`. You could override `equals` on the client class and have it only check certain fields. Alternatively, iterate through the list and check manually.

Answer (score 1):

What **@El Sam** answer is OK but it is not good for the real word because there may be two persons having the same FirstName, LastName, and Age so using equals/hashcode is not a good choice.

For your case. It is better if write your own function. Just write a loop and check the condition.

If you are using Java 8, you can use Lambda expression.

```
    myClientList.stream().anyMatch( r -> 

        r.getFirstName().equals(client.getFirstName()) &&
        r.getLastName().equals(client.getLastName()) &&
        r.getAge() == client.getAge()
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `contains` method is based on the `equals` method of your `Client` class, so you should ovveride the `equals`method to suit you needs, do as fellow:

```
 @Override
public boolean equals(Object object){
    if(object == null)
        return false;

    else if(!(object instanceof Client))
        return false;

    else {
        Client client = (Client)object;

        if(firstName.equals(client.getFirstName()) && 
               lastName.equals(client.getLastName() &&
               age.equals(client.getAge()))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Otherwise you can check for these attributes manually while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

Of contains return True you can iterate collection and find this object and exclude properties

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.List.contains(Object o)` relies on the equality of the objects in term of `Object.equals(Object o)` method.
It has a strong semantic.

Knowing if a object has some properties equal with another object, such as first name and last name should not have relation with `equals` method because it is not relevant to identify a client (it is not enough as @Loc has mentioned). It is rather a search method with some criterias.

So, At your place, I would create a service to do search operations on clients or I would create my own List which implements `List` but which also provides a find method which matches with my needs.